# Summing of individual numbers in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add up all the numbers in each array and print out the total sum of that array. I'm not sure how to get this code done.

Example:

```
var myArray = [123, 456, 789]
```

I want the program to print out 6,15,24.

Since 1+2+3 = 6, 4+5+6=15 and 7+8+9= 24.

How would I go about adding each individual number in that array?

Comment: var myArray = [123,457,789]

Comment: You might consider [*map*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map) to create a new array from values in the current array, and [*reduce*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) to create a single value from the digits in each number.

Comment: I hope your problem is solved, If it is consider accepting the best answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

With ES2015 [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax

```
myArray.map(el => el.toString().split('').reduce((sum, b) => sum + +b, 0));
```

```js
var myArray = [123, 456, 789];

var resultArr = myArray.map(el => el.toString().split('').reduce((sum, b) => sum + +b, 0));

console.log(resultArr);
document.body.innerHTML = resultArr; // FOR DEMO ONLY
```

In ES5:

```
myArray.map(function (el) {
    return el.toString().split('').reduce(function (sum, b) {
        return sum + +b
    }, 0);
});
```

```js
var myArray = [123, 456, 789];

var resultArr = myArray.map(function (el) {
    return el.toString().split('').reduce(function (sum, b) {
        return sum + +b
    }, 0);
});

console.log(resultArr);
document.body.innerHTML = resultArr;
```

Comment: Arrow functions save some space over `arr.map(function(n){return (''+n).split('').reduce(function(sum, n){return sum + +n;},0);})` but support isn't ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decompose each to number to its digits, you can use modulo operator for that.

For example, X mod 10 will always get the rightmost digit from X, and to remove the last digit of X you have to make an integer division, X div 10.

```
function parse(array) {
  return array.map(function(item) {
    var n = 0;
    while (item > 0) {
      n += item % 10;
      item = Math.floor(item/10);
    }

    return n;
  });
}
```