# Mapping and reducing new int array issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

```
var strings = [ '234-496-7459', '760-644-0201', '555-222-3333' ];
var ints = [];
console.log(strings);

strings.forEach(function(entry) {

    var ints = entry.replace(/-/g, '');
    console.log(ints);

});

var myResults = ints.map(function (el) {
    return el.toString().split('').reduce(function (sum, b) {
        return sum + +b;
    }, 0);
});

console.log(myResults);
```

I have an array of strings that I want to take out the dashes then store the new arrays as ints. I am trying to reduce each array of `ints` to create a `myResults` that print out 53, 30, 33. I know there is something wrong with this code because the mapping and reduce doesn't want to work.

Comment: Why not using the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34985400/2025923) of your previous question [Summing of individual numbers in an array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985280/summing-of-individual-numbers-in-an-array-in-javascript) `var ints = myArray.map(el => el.toString().split('').reduce((sum, b) => sum + +b, 0));`

Comment: Your `ints` is empty.  You want `map()`.

Comment: Hey Tushar, honestly i am very new to this and i am having a hard time grasping how to use map.

Comment: Here is doc for `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

You need to push `entry` values in `ints` array after `replace`

```js
var strings = [ '234-496-7459', '760-644-0201', '555-222-3333' ];
var ints = [];

strings.forEach(function(entry) {
    ints.push(entry.replace(/-/g, ''));
});

var myResults = ints.map(function (el) {
    return el.toString().split('').reduce(function (sum, b) {
        return sum + +b;
    }, 0);
});

alert(myResults);
```

Comment: Use `map()`, not `push()`.

Comment: @SLaks, Could not get you!

Comment: @RayonDabre He's saying, use `map` on original array and catch the result in the `ints` array. EX: `var ints = myArray.map(el => el.replace(/-/g, '').toString().split('').reduce((sum, b) => sum + +b, 0));`

Comment: @Tushar, Flow of the code posted in the question does not say so :( I just corrected what was missing!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for another way, you can use

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.

1. You can use RegEx `/\d/g` with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get individual numbers as an array.

   ```
   var ints = arr.map(el => el.match(/\d/g, '').reduce((sum, a) => sum + +a, 0));
   ```

   `\d` matches a single digit. `g` is global flag, to get all the possible matches.

```js
var arr = ['234-496-7459', '760-644-0201', '555-222-3333'];

var ints = arr.map(el => el.match(/\d/g, '').reduce((sum, a) => sum + +a, 0));

console.log(ints);
document.write(ints);
```

2. `String#replace` and `String#split` can also be used.

   ```
   var ints = arr.map(el => el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce((sum, a) => sum + +a, 0));
   ```

```js
var arr = ['234-496-7459', '760-644-0201', '555-222-3333'];

var ints = arr.map(el => el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce((sum, a) => sum + +a, 0));

console.log(ints);
document.write(ints);
```

Equivalent code in ES5

```
var ints = arr.map(function (el) {
    return el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce(function (sum, a) {
        return sum + +a;
    }, 0);
});
```

```js
var arr = ['234-496-7459', '760-644-0201', '555-222-3333'];

var ints = arr.map(function(el) {
  return el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce(function(sum, a) {
    return sum + +a;
  }, 0);
});
console.log(ints);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your statements like this (in a working snipppet):

```js
    var strings = [ '234-496-7459', '760-644-0201', '555-222-3333' ];
    
    var ints = strings.map(function(item) {
        return item.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce(function(total, val) {
            return total + +val;
        }, 0);
    });

    document.write(JSON.stringify(ints));
```

Explanation:

1. You want to convert one array to another so use `.map()` not `.forEach()`.
2. Then, right in the `.map()` callback, you can convert the string to total.
3. `.replace(/-/g, '').split('')` gets rid of the dashes and turns it into an array of letters.
4. `.reduce()` then runs on that array to sum up all the digits.

Answer (score 0):

Approach this in top-down fashion, step-by-step. For each step, we will write a little spec so we are perfectly clear on what we want to do. If we write the spec well, then the JS will follow easily.

We want to write a function `sum_digits_of_array`, for which the spec is:

> **`sum_digits_of_array`**
>   Given an input array, return a new array, where each element is the sum of the digits of the corresponding element from the original array.

That is exactly the definition of `map`, so we can write:

```
function sum_digits_of_array(a) { return a.map(sum_digits); }
```

Now we just need to write `sum_digits`. We will also write a spec for that:

> **`sum_digits`**
>   Given an input string, return the sum of the digits of the string.

That's easy enough:

```
function sum_digits(s) { return sum(digits(s)); }
```

Now for `digits`. Again we will write a little spec for ourselves:

> **`digits`**
>   Given a input string, return array of individual digits, as numbers.

Instead of thinking of this as removing dashes and then splitting, we will use `RegExp#match` to just extract the digits:

```
function digits(s) { return s.match(/\d/g) . map(Number); }
```

Then

> **`sum`**
>   Given an array of numbers, return the sum of all the numbers.

This is the definition of `reduce`, so

```
function sum(a) { return a.reduce(add); }
```

Then

> **`add`**
>   Given two numbers, return the result of adding them

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

That's it. So the entire solution, which is slightly more compact if we use ES6 arrow functions:

```
function sum_digits_of_array(a) {
  const sum_digits = s      => sum(digits(s));
  const digits     = s      => s.match(/\d/g) . map(Number);
  const sum        = a      => a . reduce(add);
  const add        = (a, b) => a + b;

  return a . map(sum_digits);
}
```

Why code in this fashion? There are a number of good reasons.

1. You can read the code and tell what it's doing.
2. Related to that, it's easy to figure out where to modify the code if the problem changes.
3. We can easily test each little function to make sure it's working right.
4. The little functions we wrote might come in handy when solving a related problem, so we reduce the amount of work we have to do in the future.